# App keeps stopping at runtime, on both real and virtual devices

Tags: android

So recently I tried making an app and long story short, the app can't run on my emulator. The android app is connected to my firebase by the way. Anyways, the app keeps stopping. The logcat shows this:https://i.stack.imgur.com/LA07Y.png.

I am not sure whether it is a problem with my database or android studios, Pls tell me how to fix it!

Here's the logcat:

```
 06-15 15:50:32.375 17961-17961/com.oakieandco.verfundenproject E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.oakieandco.verfundenproject, PID: 17961
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzbqo()Z in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.oakieandco.verfundenproject-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
        at com.oakieandco.verfundenproject.Signin.onCreate(Signin.java:32)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6912)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2877)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2985)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1635)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6692)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1468)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1358)
```

If im not mistaken, it references this part of my code:

```
    final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    final DatabaseReference table_user = database.getReference("User");

    signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            table_user.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    User user= dataSnapshot.child(edtid.getText().toString()).getValue(User.class);
                    if (dataSnapshot.child(edtid.getText().toString()).exists()) {
                        if (user.getPassword().equals(edtpassword.getText().toString())) {
                            Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "Login successful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "Login unsuccesful", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "User not found.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
```

I then reran the app and the good ol' logcat showed me this:

Emulator: [10032]:WARNING:android/android-emu/android/base/async/AsyncSocketServer.cpp:99:Error when accepting host connectionError message: Unknown error

This is my build.gradle section:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'


    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

Comment: Can you show your gradle-imports? Sounds like missing google play services or conflicted version number

Comment: Ummm...what do you mean by gradle imports? The gradle build didnt show errors, so doesn't that mean the gradle has no problems?

Comment: I mean your `build.gradle` file, section `dependencies`

Answer (score 0):

Do you used Proguard in your app if yes than change your proguard rules it's likely proguard restrict that class from adding into apk

if not than add multidex library

Comment: How do you add multidex libraries, because I didnt use Proguard

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex   guide to add multidex